# Check if there is an app listening to my intent

Tags: android, android-intent

How to know if the intent I am going to publish is going to be answered in advance?

After building an intent, I tried this, which does not work:

```java
Intent fc = ....
                
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = manager.queryIntentActivities(fc, 0);            
startActivityForResult(fc, 1);
```

Despite the fact that `list` has 0 elements, an app was opened by the intent.

Comment: What version of Android did you test with? If the answer is Android 11 or higher, do you have a `<queries>` element in your manifest to deal with [the package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)?

Comment: Android 11. Yes, you nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android 11 and higher, to use many (most?) methods on `PackageManager`, you need to have a `<queries>` element in your manifest, identifying the apps (or criteria for apps) that you want to find via `PackageManager`. Without that `<queries>` element, the [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) rules will limit you results to your own app and some system apps.

Answer (score 0):

**Or, set MATCH_ALL to prevent any filtering of the results**

**public static final int MATCH_ALL = 131072;**

There are more flags to try. Replace **0** with others.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: Tried several ones, in particular, `PackageManager.MATCH_ALL`. None worked.